# Creating Asymmetric Key in Azure SQL Server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, .net-assembly, public-key

I'm trying to create an asymmetric key from a file (Executable) in Azure SQL server. Basically I want to [call Azure REST API](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/italian_premier_center_for_sql_server/2013/07/04/call-azure-rest-api-from-sql-server/) from Azure SQL.

I tried with the Queries like

```
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY SampleAzureKey FROM EXECUTABLE FILE ='c:\Test\SampleAzure.dll';


CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY SampleAzureKey AUTHORIZATION deevita 
     FROM FILE = 'c:\Test\SampleAzure.dll'  
        ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<strongpass>';
```

But I got the error:

```
File based statement options are not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

I know that Azure SQL couldn't able to see my Location as `c:\Test\SampleAzure.dll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FROM FILE clause you is not supported in the CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY statement in Azure SQL Database. In addition, CLR is not supported either, so will not be able to call REST APIs. The steps in the [Call Azure REST API from SQL Server](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/italian_premier_center_for_sql_server/2013/07/04/call-azure-rest-api-from-sql-server/)  article apply to SQL Server, not Azure SQL Database.

Thanks,

Jakub